# Entity Framework Core 2.1 Chaining OnModelBuilder HasKey and HasData

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.1

I'm trying to seed my database when I create my models and coincidentally one of my tables(UserRoles) has keys in both of their columns. When I place a the HasData the next row after the HasKey and run the add-migration command, I get this error:

> An attempt was made to use the model while it was being created. A
>   DbContext instance cannot be used inside OnModelCreating in any way
>   that makes use of the model that is being created.

If I remove the HasKey or HasData, the seeding goes on as per normal. 
What is the proper way to seed data for that table while also defining both columns as keys?

Here is my code:

```
modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(schema: DatabaseGlobals.SchemaName);
modelBuilder.Entity<Applications>().HasData(application);
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUsers>().HasData(user);
modelBuilder.Entity<Roles>().HasData(role);
modelBuilder.Entity<UserRoles>().HasData(UserRoles);
modelBuilder.Entity<UserRoles>().HasKey(k=>new { k.UserId, k.RoleId});
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().HasKey(k => new { k.UserId, k.RoleId });
modelBuilder.Entity<EventLogs>();
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```

If I combined HasKey and HasData, this is the error I get:

> KeyBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'HasData'

EDIT: Added full error

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: An attempt was made to use the model while it was being created. A DbContext instance cannot be used inside OnModelCreating in any way that makes use of the model that is being created.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.EntityType.GetData(Boolean providerValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateData(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.SqlServerModelValidator.Validate(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalAccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

Comment: Don't chain the calls. There's no reason to. The two methods configure different things.

Comment: But if I put  the hasdata below, I get the error as stated above?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I need to chain it because I can't add Keys to the models directly.

Comment: if you get that error it means you are trying to use the *wrong* methods to do whatever you are trying to do. `HasKey` is used to specify a *Primary Key* so calling `HasData()` on a KeyBuilder is meaningless.

Comment: In fact, you should clean up the question. You are asking two different things -how to configure a model and how to seed it.  You also need to specify *which* EF core version you use. I suspect 2.1? ASP.NET Core is *not* a data access framework. It's a web application framework

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I get the Keybuilder error because its thinking that I'm chaining the HasData to HasKey instead of the modelbuilder directly. And I already know that I can't add [Key] directly to the model because it will ask me to do it in the modelbuilder. 
I'm using EF2.1 which is what I'm assuming is together in .NET Core 2.1?

Comment: Double click on the error and the cursor will move to the line that caused the compilation error. The error includes the line and column number of the call that caused the problem. What you posted here can't be used to reproduce the problem. For example why the double calls to `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);`? Does this context inherit from another class?

Comment: Sorry about that, I made a mistake when I pasted my code. I've also added the full error stack. I can't find the line and column number of the call though.

Comment: The problem line is `modelBuilder.Entity<UserRoles>().HasData(UserRoles);`. It has to be after defining the key and also should not pass `UserRoles` **DbSet** but some in memory data.

Comment: @IvanStoev oh man you found the issue! Thank you!